# mongoose - concatenating docs' arrays, aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got following query used for concatenating `users` arrays from many docs, which works fine in mongo shell and returning results:

```
db.circles.aggregate([{
  $unwind: '$users'
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    _users: {
      $addToSet : '$users'
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    users: '$_users'
  }
}]);
```

I was trying to do the same by mongoose that way:

```
Circle.aggregate([{
  $unwind: '$users',
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    _users: {
      $addToSet: '$users',
    },
  },
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    users: '$_users',
  },
}]).exec((err, users) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log(users);
});
```

and that way...

```
Circle.aggregate()
  .unwind('$users')
  .group({
    _id: null,
    _users: {
      $addToSet: '$users',
    },
  })
  .project({
    _id: 0,
    users: '$_users',
  })
  .exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log(users);
  });
}
```

...and also that way:)

```
Circle.collection.aggregate([{
  $unwind: "$users"
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    _users: {
      $addToSet: "$users"
    },
  },
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    users: "$_users"
  },
}], (err, users) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log(users);
});
```

The results of all of them are an empty arrays with no errors. What's going on?

Comment: Can you try each stage on its own and see if they return results? E.g. remove the group and project states and see if the unwind is producing results. Then add in group, then add in project.

Comment: OMG, I've found the bug - now, it's working. The bad model was required at the top of file... Shame on me! haha^^ Thanx!